# Finding device uniqueness using Canvas Fingerprinting

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, api

Currently I am using Canvas Fingerprinting and other device parameters to find the unique device. But in recent post i came to hear that Canvas Fingerprinting is going to be blocked by Firefox browser. So i need alternate solution for identifying devices effectively. Can anyone suggest me a effective way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var _speedconstant = 8.9997e-9; //if speed=(c*a)/t, then constant=(s*t)/a and time=(a*c)/s
var d = new Date();
var amount = 150000000;
var estprocessor = 1.7; //average processor speed, in GHZ
console.log("JSBenchmark by Aaron Becker, running loop "+amount+" times.     Estimated time (for "+estprocessor+"ghz processor) is "+(Math.round(((_speedconstant*amount)/estprocessor)*100)/100)+"s");
for (var i = amount; i>0; i--) {} 
var newd = new Date();
var accnewd = Number(String(newd.getSeconds())+"."+String(newd.getMilliseconds()));
var accd = Number(String(d.getSeconds())+"."+String(d.getMilliseconds())); 
var di = accnewd-accd;
//console.log(accnewd,accd,di);
if (d.getMinutes() != newd.getMinutes()) {
di = (60*(newd.getMinutes()-d.getMinutes()))+di}
spd = ((_speedconstant*amount)/di);
console.log("Time: "+Math.round(di*1000)/1000+"s, estimated speed: "+Math.round(spd*1000)/1000+"GHZ");
```

This utility was free. It's probably better for validating performance than for fingerprinting.